# How does Azure ML handle categorical columns during training a linear or logistic regression model?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

How does Azure ML handle categorical columns during training a linear regression model? A linear regression model takes continuous values. However, even though I haven't changed anything of those categorical columns, Azure ML trains linear and logistic regression without error. So I would like to know how Azure ML manages to process categorical columns behind the scene. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the model you are using, but you can get clues to how it's done by right-clicking on the "Train Model" element in your experiment, then clicking "Trained Model" -> "Visualize". The visualization will show you how it's used the supplied data.

Answer (score 0):

The linear regression module will only take numeric independent variables. Are you sure you had this working with categoricals in the linear regression?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905978.aspx